# Verify PayPal payment

Tags: php

I'm creating a site with a payment system, I'll explain you the problem with the code :

Order.php

```
<div class="bg-login" style="background-color: #fef8f8;">
    <div id="login">
        <div class="order-header">
            Détails de la commande
        </div>
        <div class="order-content">
            <h3>Prix:</h3>
            <p><?php echo $price; ?> €</p>
            <h3>Commande:</h3>
            <p><?php echo $paypal['item_name']; ?></p>
            <h3>Serveur:</h3>
            <p><?php echo strtoupper($server); ?></p>
            <form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" id="paypal-form" method="POST">
                <input type="hidden" id="cmd" name="cmd" value="<?php echo $paypal['cmd']; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" id="return" name="return" value="<?php echo $paypal['return']; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" id="currency_code" name="currency_code" value="<?php echo $paypal['currency_code']; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" id="business" name="business" value="<?php echo $paypal['business']; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" id="amount" name="amount" value="<?php echo $paypal['amount']; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" id="item_name" name="item_name" value="<?php echo $paypal['item_name']; ?>">
                <button type="button" onclick="payment()" class="order-submit">Payer <?php echo $price; ?>  €</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my page which get me the price of the order to Paypal. And with this :

```
<input type="hidden" id="return" name="return" value="<?php echo $paypal['return']; ?>">
```

I can, after the transaction, get the user on a page "Paypal.php" when the transaction is done.

On this page paypal.php i'll ask the user to create an account after his order (will add order infos in the database when he has created his account).

The problem is, I had as idea to make every order infos in sessions variables to get them in paypal.php, but everyone can go on paypal.php even if they didn't payed, so they just have to go on order.php then go to paypal.php to get a free order.
I'd like to know how is possible to get the status of the order with paypal on paypal.php, I looks a bit on paypal doc, there's a `IPN` thing to know the status of the transaction, but I don't know how to use it :( If someone could help me to know if the user has well payed on paypal.php, would be really awesome And If you've any smart idea instead of take the order infos in sessions, tell me, I've no idea for it.

Thanks !!

Comment: paypal returns the token and the payment id, which the user originally doesn't have ... this is the data you have to check and eventuall store.

Comment: What does it means ?

Comment: maybe you should read documentation.

Comment: I readed, but I didn't really understood, that's why I'm here ^^